# Better way of grabbing elements from JSON object?

Tags: python, json

This program takes input from a web socket in the form of a JSON object that represents the order book of multiple bitcoin exchanges combined. I have modified the example by deleting the other bids and asks from the first section. The first bid and first ask are all I need to grab.

```
{
    "payload": {
        "asks": [
            [
                8329.01,
                0.19875089,
                "gemini"
            ],
        ],
        "bids": [
            [
                8330.55,
                16.04230494,
                "market1"
            ],
        ],
        "currency": "usd",
        "lastpublished": 1579970355700,
        "lastupdated": 1579970355660,
        "market_making": {
            "asks": [
                [
                    8344.88,
                    0.57580068,
                    "bittrex"
                ],
                [
                    8336.48,
                    2,
                    "bitstamp"
                ],
                [
                    8330.56,
                    0.18606522,
                    "market1"
                ],
                [
                    8329.01,
                    0.19875089,
                    "gemini"
                ]
            ],
            "bids": [
                [
                    8325.271,
                    0.0766122,
                    "bittrex"
                ],
                [
                    8325.51,
                    1.1984,
                    "bitstamp"
                ],
                [
                    8329,
                    13.07297146,
                    "gemini"
                ],
                [
                    8330.55,
                    16.04230494,
                    "market1"
                ]
            ]
        },
        "pair": "btcusd",
        "timestamps": {
            "bitstamp": [
                1579970355573,
                1579970355573
            ],
            "bittrex": [
                1579970354809,
                1579970355010
            ],
            "gemini": [
                1579970355374,
                1579970355376
            ],
            "market1": [
                1579970354799,
                1579970354799
            ]
        }
    },
    "recipient": "orderbook.sfox.btcusd",
    "sequence": 2,
    "timestamp": 1579970355757434509
}
```

When making my program I couldn't get json.loads() to return a list or dict, instead I could only get a string result. My code right now just finds the slice where both of these elements should be, but that seems inefficient, and causes issues when the message isn't as I expect.

```
async def main(uri):
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as ws:
        subscribe_msg = {
            "type": "subscribe",
            "feeds": ["orderbook.sfox.btcusd"],
        }
        await ws.send(json.dumps(subscribe_msg))
        async for msg in ws:
            #print(msg)
            json.loads(msg)
            if msg[2] == "s":
                ask = float(msg[msg.find("asks") + 8 : msg.find(",", msg.find("asks")+8)])
                asksize = float(msg[msg.find(",", msg.find("asks")+8)+1:
                                    msg.find(",", msg.find(",", msg.find("asks")+8)+1)])
                bid = float(msg[msg.find("bids") + 8 : msg.find(",", msg.find("bids")+8)])
                bidsize = float(msg[msg.find(",", msg.find("bids")+8)+1:
                                    msg.find(",", msg.find(",", msg.find("bids")+8)+1)])
                time = msg[msg.find("timestamp") + 11 :msg.find(",",msg.find("timestamp") + 11)]
                oppmonitor(bid, bidsize, ask, asksize)
                print("Time", time, "Bid", bid, "Bid Size", bidsize, "Ask", ask, "Ask Size", asksize)
            else:
                print("Starting Message")
```

The program works I just need a more efficient way of getting the bid and ask. Preferably one that doesn't involve slicing the json object.

Comment: `json.loads(msg)` You're calling `loads` but not saving the result.  Try `mydict = json.loads(msg)`.

Comment: You're right I wasn't calling it. When I try and print print `print(mydict['payload'])` I get the error: KeyError: 'payload' EDIT: nvm I just realized its cause im not specifying where in the payload it should call